# Why Java Interpreter can't find packages that I specified in CLASSPATH?

Tags: java, import, package, classpath

I have a package books.grokkingAlgorithms. There are some classes, obviously. I specified `CLASSPATH` (made an environment variable) pointing to `.;C:/DOC/JavaT`:

[image: CLASSPATH set image]

Then added `books/grokkingAlgorithms` directory (with classes in it) to `C:/DOC/JavaT`. After that, I created new project and tried to import `books.grokkingAlgorithms` package in it:

[image: error image]

I really don't understand the reason. I thought that I need to specify `CLASSPATH` and add to that path directories with `someClassName.class` files and then Java interpreter finds it by itself.
CLASSPATH + packagePath -> .;C:/DOC/JavaT/books/grokkingAlgorithms (We get something like this, aren't we?)

As written here:

[image: Description of Java interpreter actions]

I've spent so much time on it and don't want merely give up, but it confused me formidably. I appreciate any help with it greatly.

Comment: I think you want to set the _CLASSPATH_ to `C:/DOC/JavaT` (so drop the `.;`). Also if using Windows, go with \ instead of / (so `C:\DOC\JavaT`).

Comment: @Fullslack.dev: `.;` just means that the current directory is also on the CLASSPATH, it should not in itself cause a problem.

Comment: Ederika, it looks like your second screenshot is from some IDE. Note that IDEs usually have their own way of configuring the classpath of a given project, so they tend to ignore environment variables like `CLASSPATH`. What editor/IDE have you used there and how did you configure the project?

Comment: I printed `.;` to set current directory as well. I changed everyything as you said, but nothing occured (I still can't import)

Comment: I've used **Intelij IDEA** - @JoachimSauer

Comment: @EderikaBartison: then ignore the `CLASSPATH` variable (that's used by the `java` and `javac` executable, but not by other tools) and check the configuration of the project inside IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @JoachimSauer You mean to delete `CLASSPATH` variable? But how can I sepcify packages?.. And what do you mean _configuration of the projet_? I'm sorry, but could you tell me how people import their own packages, at usual? It seems to me that your Java knowledge is really good. (and why don't you use IntelliJ IDEA?)

Comment: The documentation you present in your post describes how to set up your system to *manually compile using the `javac` command and run it using the `java` command*. You are using very different tools (IntelliJ IDEA) to build and run your code. So **either** you switch which tools you use **or** you switch which documentation your reference. Since a lot of beginners tutorials assume the `javac`/`java` combination I think it's simpler to switch to that for now and switch back to the IDE when you have a solid understanding of the basics.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thank you, now I understood my problem. That _documentation_ is form _"Thinking in Java"_ book (Bruce Eckel). But could you tell me please, how I can import some package to my project with IntellIJ IDEA? I really need that and cannot find the answer anywhere. I won't write here, if I wasn't so confused. (Maybe, I'm a bit annoying, but I can't lost my chance to ask this question: Can I write you directly? I would really want to ask some questions someone experienced like you)

Comment: @JoachimSauer By the way, Bruce Eckel said about using of `package` keyword. (and he was using IDE, not `java` or `javac` comands in cmd). The more I know, the more I understand that I know nothing. . .